# Java NumberFormatException Legacy Code

Tags: java, exception, numbers, locale, numberformatexception

I have a legacy program (java 1.4) running under Tomcat/Jboss, however, i have copy it to a new server (java 1.7) and it throws the following exception.

```
java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "0000000000000000009011,00"
    sun.misc.FloatingDecimal.readJavaFormatString(FloatingDecimal.java:1250)
    java.lang.Double.valueOf(Double.java:504)
    java.lang.Double.<init>(Double.java:597)
```

Since i don't have access to the source, is there any way to fix this? i haven't try with java 1.4 for the moment

Comment: I think, its not due to to java version, remove comma.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You schould look to jvm parameters on old server. Your language parameters will change comma to dot actually so you do not need any code changes.

Answer (score 0):

I think its not due to java version. Replace `comma(,)`  with `""` or `period(.)`

For example conside a string : `String str = "0000000000000000009011,00";`

Now you can try -

```
double result = Double.valueOf(str.replace(",", "."));
```

or

```
double result = Double.valueOf(str.replace(",", ""));
```

Answer (score 0):

Rather use [`NumberFormat`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/text/NumberFormat.html) for parsing:

```
NumberFormat format = NumberFormat.getInstance(Locale.FRANCE);
Number number = format.parse("0000000000000000009011,00");
double d = number.doubleValue();
```

This way you can select the right locale for the number representation. In the example above I used France - they use a comma for the decimal point.